# Running apache flink in organization which pulls packages from internal JFrog artifactory

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to build and run the examples from the apache flink github repository. Our organization uses JFrog artifactory (formerly and still referred to as Nexus) to pull packages so initially I got errors that the `SNAPSHOT` packages were unavailable. I checked JFrog and found that flink packages were there and were on the 1.17 version. I then switched branches to `release-1.17` and modified all the pom.xml files to point to version `1.17.0`. Maven did sync at this point.

When I did a `mvn clean install` the job started installing dependencies and running unit tests. This ran for quite some time before failing a unit test in the `flink-table` package and aborting. When I checked again there was a new commit out so I pulled from origin. Now when I try to run `mvn clean` I get the following error.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project flink-dist_2.12: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.flink:flink-dist_2.12:jar:1.17.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.flink:flink-dist-scala_2.12:jar:1.17.0, org.apache.flink:flink-examples-streaming-state-machine_2.12:jar:1.17.0, org.apache.flink:flink-fs-hadoop-shaded:jar:1.17.0, org.apache.flink:flink-s3-fs-base:jar:1.17.0: org.apache.flink:flink-dist-scala_2.12:jar:1.17.0 was not found in http://artifacts.myOrg.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Is the issue that we don't have the proper packages in Artifactory? Is there a reason this worked yesterday before the latest commit?

Thanks for any and all help

EDIT: I tried `mvn clean install -U` and am now getting this error.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.github.zentol.japicmp:japicmp-maven-plugin:0.17.1.1_m325:cmp (default) on project flink-metrics-core: There is at least one incompatibility: java.lang.annotation.Annotation[java.lang.annotation.Annotation]:INTERFACE_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.annotation.Experimental:SUPERCLASS_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.annotation.Experimental:CLASS_REMOVED,java.lang.annotation.Annotation[java.lang.annotation.Annotation]:INTERFACE_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.annotation.Internal:SUPERCLASS_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.annotation.Internal:CLASS_REMOVED,java.lang.annotation.Annotation[java.lang.annotation.Annotation]:INTERFACE_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.annotation.Public:SUPERCLASS_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.annotation.Public:CLASS_REMOVED,java.lang.annotation.Annotation[java.lang.annotation.Annotation]:INTERFACE_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.annotation.PublicEvolving:SUPERCLASS_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.annotation.PublicEvolving:CLASS_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.byCode(java.lang.String):METHOD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.current():METHOD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.isNewerVersionThan(org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion):METHOD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.rangeOf(org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion):METHOD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.toString():METHOD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.valueOf(java.lang.String):METHOD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.values():METHOD_REMOVED,java.lang.constant.Constable[java.lang.constant.Constable]:INTERFACE_REMOVED,java.lang.Comparable[java.lang.Comparable]:INTERFACE_REMOVED,java.io.Serializable[java.io.Serializable]:INTERFACE_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion:SUPERCLASS_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.v1_8:FIELD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.v1_9:FIELD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.v1_6:FIELD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.v1_7:FIELD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.v1_4:FIELD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.v1_5:FIELD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.v1_13:FIELD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.v1_14:FIELD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.v1_11:FIELD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.v1_12:FIELD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.v1_10:FIELD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.v1_3:FIELD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.v1_17:FIELD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.v1_15:FIELD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion.v1_16:FIELD_REMOVED,org.apache.flink.FlinkVersion:CLASS_REMOVED -> [Help 1]

I tried downgrading flink to 1.17.1 on my machine but it did not help